# NavigationDestination in subViews

Tags: swiftui

I have a main view with a NavigationStack, NavigationLink and navigationDestination.
From that view I need to go to a second view, where the user will input the name, and then navigate to a third view:

```
struct MainView: View {
   var body: some View {
      NavigationStack {
         NavigationLink(value: "second") {
            Text("Second View")
         }
         .navigationDestination(for: String.self, destination: { _ in
            SecondaryView()
         })
      }
   }
}

struct SecondaryView: View {
   @State var name = ""
   var body: some View {
      VStack {
         TextField("", text: $name)
         NavigationLink(value: "third") {
            Text("Third View")
         }
         .navigationDestination(for: String.self), destination: { _ in
            ThirdView(name: name)
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I know I can create an enum an switch over it on the MainView, but the problem is: I can't say something like that:

```
ThirdView()
```

on the MainView, because the user hasnt submited the name yet.

I need to navigate from the second view. I tried changing the secondView value to Int, and then it worked. Something like this:

```
struct SecondaryView: View {
   @State var name = ""
   var body: some View {
      VStack {
         TextField("", text: $name)
         NavigationLink(value: 3) {
            Text("Third View")
         }
         .navigationDestination(for: Int.self), destination: { _ in
            ThirdView(name: name)
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Is there any other way to do that without needing to use different data types? Because that way I'll need to create one data type for each screen, and that makes me feel like I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Probably it is easier to use destination/label NavigationLink instead of value based ones.
Especially since you aren't using the path anyway.

```
NavigationLink {
    %destination%
} label: {
    %label%
}
```

It would be possible to bind a path to the NavigationStack, and then inspect the length of the path, at which position your element is.
But that's messy, since having a repeating value in the path makes it difficult to make the right choices.